# Add fileupload input fields inside multiple div at a same time according to radiobox selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, frontend

I have a input field that takes numeric inputs. Then i have a button which display the number of divs as per that input. after displaying div there is two radio-box buttons (paired end and single end) if I select paired end then i want two file upload fields in each divs. and if i select single end then i want only one file upload fields in each div.
I have tried but fileupload fields working on only first div.

```js
function CreateText() {
  var text = `<div class="row border-top py-3"> 
         <div class="col-md-3">
          <label">sample name *</label></br>                           
           <input type="sample" id="sample" name="sample[]">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3" style="display:none" id="showsingle">
                         <div class="form-group">
                          
                           <label for="form_upload">Upload file *</label></br>                           
                           <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename1[]">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                       
                       <div class="col-md-3" style="display:none" id="showpair">
                         <div class="form-group">
                   
                           <label for="form_upload">Upload file *</label></br>                           
                           <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename2[]">
                           <label for="form_upload">Upload file *</label></br>                           
                           <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename2[]">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-3 d-grid">
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <button class="btn btn-danger remove_add_btn">Remove</button>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>`;

  var textCount = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < $('#textInput').val(); i++) {
    html = document.getElementById('divDynamicTexts').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('divDynamicTexts').innerHTML = html + text.replace('', i);


  }

}

function onlyOne() {
  let SradioBox = document.getElementById("singleradio"),
    Sfileupload = document.getElementById("showsingle"),
    PradioBox = document.getElementById("pairedradio"),
    Pfileupload = document.getElementById("showpair");

  if (SradioBox.checked == true) {
    Sfileupload.style.display = "block",
      Pfileupload.style.display = "none";

  } else if (PradioBox.checked == true) {
    Pfileupload.style.display = "block",
      Sfileupload.style.display = "none";

  } else {
    Pfileupload.style.display = "none",
      Sfileupload.style.display = "none";

  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.remove_add_btn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let row_item = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    $(row_item).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-center">

  <input type="text" id="textInput" value="" />&nbsp;
  <input type="button" id="" value="Create upload fields" onclick="CreateText();" />
  <div class="col-md-4" id="filebutton">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="form_need">Library Type *</label>
      </br>
      <div class="px-2">
        <label for="myradio">Single end:</label>
        <input type="radio" id="singleradio" name="check" onclick="onlyOne();">
        <label for="myradio">Paired end:</label>
        <input type="radio" id="pairedradio" name="check" onclick="onlyOne();">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="divDynamicTexts"></div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID attributes **must** be unique. It would be better to remove the IDs altogether ( or change to `dataset` attributes perhaps ) and use a `delegated event listener` to process the various clicks related to the task of adding/removing dynamic elements.

In the code below all ID attributes were either removed entirely or changed to `data-id` type values.

To avoid the need to process different form file input fields at the server the `file-input` fields are named the same but have an index so can be identified more readily in PHP ( or whatever backend you have )

The `delegated` listener, because it is bound to the document, will work for all elements whether or not they are static or added dynamically and makes heavy use of the `event.target` property to help identify the element that invoked the event.

The `label` element was being used incorrectly previously. If the form-input is within the `label` then there is no need for the `for="ID"` syntax ( note that the ID should be the ID of the input element to which the label belongs! ) - as it was the label's appeared to have a `for` attribute which did not related to an element in the form!

Using `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` you can easily identify nodes of interest within the DOM so button clicks or radio button selection can fire a query to find nodes that are relevant - thus simplifying the hiding/showing of the file input elements.

```js
const strhtml = `

<div data-id="dynrow" class="row border-top py-3">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>sample name *<input type="text" name="sample[]"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="display:none" data-id="single" data-role="file-field">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Upload file *<input type="file" name="filename[]" disabled /></label>                   
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-md-3" style="display:none" data-id="pair" data-role="file-field">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Upload file *<input type="file" name="filename[]" disabled /></label>
            <label>Upload file *<input type="file" name="filename[]" disabled /></label>        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3 d-grid">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger remove_add_btn" data-id='remove'>Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`;






const _radio = document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"][data-id]');
const _bttn = document.querySelector('[type="button"][data-id="add"]');
const _div = document.querySelector('#divDynamicTexts');
const _input = document.querySelector('input[type="number"][data-id="textInput"]');
const _submit=document.querySelector('[type="submit"]');

let choice = false;
let qty = false;


/*
  Disable radio buttons and the "Create" button initially
  and enable when changes are made in the correct sequence.
  
  1: select quantity -> enable radio bttns
  2: select single or double -> enable "create" bttn
  3: click bttn, create as per radio selection
*/
document.addEventListener('change',e=>{
    if( e.target === _input ){
        _radio.forEach(n => {
            n.disabled = e.target.value > 0 ? false : true;
        });
        qty = e.target.value;
    }
    
    if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type=='radio' ){
        return true;
    }
    
    
    let bool=true;
    let col=[ ..._div.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]:not( [ disabled ] ), input[type="file"]:not( [ disabled ] )') ];
        col.some(n=>{
            if( n.value=='' ){
                bool=false;
                return true;
            }
        });
    
    // enable submit button if fields are all completed
    if( bool && col.length > 0 )_submit.disabled=false;
});




document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.dataset.id != null ) {
    /* 
      set global "choice" variable 
      and enable "Create" bttn.
    */
    if( e.target.type == 'radio' ) {
      choice = e.target.dataset.id;
      _bttn.disabled=false;
    }
  }
  
  /*
     If the "choice" has been made the radio
     buttons will be enabled. Based on radio
     button selected create new HTML and then 
     unhide the appropriate single/pair DIV
     element
  */
  if( choice && qty > 0 && e.target.type == 'button' ) {
    _div.innerHTML='';
    _submit.disabled=true;
    
    for( let i=0; i < qty; i++ ) _div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', strhtml );

    let expr = `div[ data-id="${choice}" ]`;
    document.querySelectorAll( expr ).forEach(n => {
        /* display the appropriate DIV containing either 1 or 2 inputs */
        n.style.display='block';
        
        /* enable input elements within this DIV that are disabled by default initially */
        n.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el=>{
            el.disabled=false;
        });
    });
  }
  
  /*
    unchanged: delete DIV & contents when "Remove" bttn is clicked.
  */
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.dataset.id != null ) {
    if( e.target.dataset.id == 'remove' ) {
      _div.removeChild( e.target.closest('[data-id="dynrow"]') );
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.px-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.px-2 label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
}

#divDynamicTexts {
  min-height: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem auto
}

div.row {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

div[data-id='single'] .form-group label {
  background: aliceblue
}

div[data-id='pair'] .form-group label {
  background: lightsteelblue
}

div[data-id] .form-group label {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}

[disabled] {
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<form method='post'>
  <div class='text-center'>
    <label class='inline bold'>Quantity: <input type='number' data-id='textInput' /></label>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <h2>Library Type</h2>
        <div class='px-2'>
          <label>Single end: <input type='radio' data-id='single' name='check' disabled /></label>
          <label>Paired end: <input type='radio' data-id='pair' name='check' disabled /></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type='button' data-id='add' value='Create upload fields' disabled />
  </div>
  <input type='submit' disabled />
  <div id='divDynamicTexts'></div>
</form>
```

Comment: working perfectly, thank you so much Professor Abronsius .
but i need one more help , if i want to shift that button at last  (after radio box) and i wand to display divs with fileupload fields (i don't want to select radio box after displaying divs but it will work after displaying divs also) .
 and after all  divs (not each divs) i need one final submit button.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you are trying to say. `"if i want to shift that button"` - which button? And Where to? `"i wand to display divs with fileupload fields"` - which `DIV`s? `"(i don't want to select radio box after displaying divs but it will work after displaying divs also"` ???

Comment: This button 
``` <input type='button' data-id='add' value='Create upload fields' /> ```
DIV s means hidden elements. 
i want to select Quantity first then, radio box (single end or pair end) and then view results by clicking  "Create upload fields" button . final result should display with radio box selection.  In previous code we are selecting radio box after displaying result(DIVs) but now i want to select radio box before .

Comment: Hello, Professor Abronsius, 
Now, I want to add a submit button at the end of the form in a disable format and it will enable only when all the inputs are filled by user. i want to submit all data in database with php which includes (Quantity, Library Type, sample name, Upload file) INPUTS.

Comment: hmm - one would typically `accept` & upvote the answer that provided the greatest help

Comment: yes please i did, can you edit now , actually today only i am using this code in my project

Comment: it is working fine but i need submit button should come after clicking create upload field button . it will show after java script code, end of the form . i tried to add submit input in java-script code it is not working

Comment: it is not working fine, after uploading file when i clicked on sample name input (if i want to edit my sample name) then why submit query disable again and i have to upload file again? I need submit button should come after clicking create upload field button . it will show after java script code, end of the form . i tried to add submit input in java-script code it is not working